# Search Results from Arxiv API different from Arxiv Advanced search

Tags: api, web-scraping, web-crawler, screen-scraping

I'm trying to get the metadata of COVID-19 related papers from [arxiv.org](http://arxiv.org).

I'm specifically interested in getting the papers given in [advanced search on arxiv](https://arxiv.org/search/advanced?advanced=&terms-0-operator=AND&terms-0-term=COVID-19&terms-0-field=title&terms-1-operator=OR&terms-1-term=SARS-CoV-2&terms-1-field=abstract&terms-3-operator=OR&terms-3-term=COVID-19&terms-3-field=abstract&terms-4-operator=OR&terms-4-term=SARS-CoV-2&terms-4-field=title&terms-5-operator=OR&terms-5-term=coronavirus&terms-5-field=title&terms-6-operator=OR&terms-6-term=coronavirus&terms-6-field=abstract&classification-physics_archives=all&classification-include_cross_list=include&date-filter_by=all_dates&date-year=&date-from_date=&date-to_date=&date-date_type=submitted_date&abstracts=show&size=200&order=-announced_date_first&source=home-covid-19). This advanced search displays a total of **1304** search results currently.

I tried replicating this advanced search with an [Arxiv API](https://arxiv.org/help/api/user-manual) search query (**ti:COVID-19+OR+abs:SARS-CoV-2+OR+abs:COVID-19+OR+ti:SARS-CoV-2+OR+ti:coronavirus+OR+abs:coronavirus**). Surprisingly, this returns only **473** search results. [This](http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?search_query=ti:COVID-19%20OR%20abs:SARS-CoV-2%20OR%20abs:COVID-19%20OR%20ti:SARS-CoV-2%20OR%20ti:coronavirus%20OR%20abs:coronavirus&sortOrder=descending&start=0&max_results=500) is a link to the API query results.

Is there some difference between the two queries that I'm missing?

Thanks