# How to query arxiv daily based on keywords and write the results in a Google doc?

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-docs

I want to find papers that are published in the [computer science section of arxiv](https://arxiv.org/list/cs/recent) **every day** based on a list of keywords and write their **titles** and **arxiv link** to my Google doc (i.e., append to the end of what's already written):

For example, the Google doc can look as follows:

1. [Test-time Augmentation for Factual Probing](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2310.17121.pdf)
2. [Controlled Decoding from Language Models](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2310.17022.pdf)

And so on...

My list of search keywords:

```
arxiv_keywords = ['machine learning', 'llm', 'potato']
```

The titles should not be case sensitive and should contain the keywords. For example, the following made up titles should be returned `Machine learninG is a mystery, LLM-based models are weird, potatoes are tasty when turned into fries`

My Google doc is located in `my_drive/Research/my_google_doc_name`

I found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64047299/how-to-query-arxiv-for-a-specific-year) that asks about querying arxiv for a specific year based on one keyword, but there are several different things in my request and theirs which complicates things to me:

1. I only need to query the [computer science section](https://arxiv.org/list/cs/recent). Based on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62368794/search-results-from-arxiv-api-different-from-arxiv-advanced-search) there seems to be a difference in returned results when querying from the general arxiv website and a more advance search.
2. I need to automatically query it once a day, so I'm not sure how to automatically update the dates.
3. I'm not sure how to modify their script to handle multiple keywords
4. I'm not sure how to append the results to a Google doc, which requires a separate query from my understanding, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248152/writing-to-a-google-document-with-python) and [here](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/move-text) and probably to enter my password somehow.

I found that I can automatically run a python script using cron following [this link](https://medium.com/@jonathanmondaut/creating-a-web-scraping-pipeline-scheduling-recurring-tasks-with-various-methods-c43fd4b44509).

Overall there seems to be a lot going on which confuses me and I'm not entirely sure how to handle all the parts.

Comment: Can you please add a [mre] to your question and also focus only on *one, specific* issue you're having instead of listing your expectations?

Comment: My one specific issue: how to query arxiv daily based on keywords and write the results in a Google doc?
The minimal reproducible example can be seen in the SO question that asks about querying arxiv for a specific year based on one keyword. If you want me to copy their code to here I can do that, but I was trying to reduce cluttering

Comment: Not a python solution but you should consider taking a look at Google's App Script at [script.google.com](https://script.google.com) which allows JS to execute and be able to work within Google Sheets, Docs, etc. I believe that might be more easier to work with considering its is product for addressing needs of users requiring custom automation such as your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Edit:

```
  - add more logging and error handling. 
  - change xml "item" as a child of the root element ("rss") to a child of "channel"
  - added the feature to send error to mail. Do not forget to change the "your-email@example.com". That code will prompt the script to ask for permission one more time. Comment or delete it if not needed.
```

##### Post:

Here is one solution. Note that it isn't using python since it seems more simple to just use one of the hundreds other much easier (and free) options to trigger such event based script.

Ignore this if python is a must, but i think that the code algorithm can be easily adapted to python if necessary. Besides that this solution should be useful to others that have a related questions so i have published it nonetheless.

Following the idea of [@MFK34](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5484849/mfk34), This will use google App scripts. Here is the code:

```js
  function fetchAndWritePapers() {
    var summary = {
      totalItems: 0,
      itemsMatched: 0,
      errors: []
    };

    try {
      Logger.log("Fetching response from arxiv.org");
      var keywords = ['Model'];
      var url = 'http://arxiv.org/rss/cs';
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
      var responseText = response.getContentText();
      var xml = XmlService.parse(responseText);
      var rootElement = xml.getRootElement();
      var channelElement = rootElement.getChild('channel');
      var items = channelElement.getChildren('item');
      summary.totalItems = items.length;
      Logger.log("totalResults got: " + items.length);
      if (items.length > 0) {
        Logger.log("Getting Google doc reference");
        // You can find your-google-doc-id in the URL of your Google Doc
        var docId = "your-google-doc-id";
        var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docId);
        var body = doc.getBody();

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
          var title = items[i].getChild('title').getText().toLowerCase();
          var link = items[i].getChild('link').getText();

          for (var j = 0; j < keywords.length; j++) {
            var temp = keywords[j].toLowerCase();
            var test = title.includes(temp);
            if (test) {
              var listItem = body.appendListItem(title);
              listItem.setLinkUrl(link);
              summary.itemsMatched++;
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      summary.errors.push('Error in fetchAndWritePapers: ' + error.toString());
      Logger.log('Summary of fetchAndWritePapers: \n' +
        'Total Items: ' + summary.totalItems + '\n' +
        'Items Matched: ' + summary.itemsMatched + '\n' +
        'Errors: ' + summary.errors.join(', '));
      Logger.log("Mailing error");
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: "your-email@example.com",
        subject: "Error in fetchAndWritePapers",
        body: 'Error in fetchAndWritePapers: ' + error.toString(),
      });
    } finally {
      Logger.log('Summary of fetchAndWritePapers: \n' +
        'Total Items: ' + summary.totalItems + '\n' +
        'Items Matched: ' + summary.itemsMatched + '\n' +
        'Errors: ' + summary.errors.join(', '));
    }
  }
```

As for triggering it everyday, app script has such a feature in the Trigger menu. It is easy to add and configure.

Note that i am using here the rss daily  news feed to get the updated articles on Computer Science. Which if i am not wrong should include all the article published that day until midnight or something similar? I don't remember where i have seen this so confirmation is needed.

Some more tweaks to the url  can be made like filtering by individual subject classes or choosing the language, but not much more.
More info about the rss feed [here](https://info.arxiv.org/help/rss.html)

About more searching power: What i have found is that the arxiv public API is kind of limited but they have an [advanced search](https://arxiv.org/search/advanced) option that is much richer than the API (like the date option). The problem is that the results are formatted in html and so on will have to use some web-scraping techniques or libraries. And i don't know about their politic on using it for such a goal.

Here are the specific steps i took.

- Login to your google account and go to [Google App Scripts Home](https://script.google.com/home/my)
- Click on the  "New project" button in the top left
- copy paste the given code and change the "your-google-doc-id" to the id of the google doc you want the titles to be added. The ID is the "big number" in the url. Ex: "1HVRgEM4h5aQwygDvKk_A-xNaJ8CUoyMZTFsChyM2tmk"
- Test the code with the "run" button at the top. If everything was ok then your google doc should have a bunch of title links added to a list.
- Now to get this to run daily: click on the clock button at the left (Triggers). In the new page, click the "add trigger" button in the bottom right.
- Just choose/experiment-with the correct options in the drop downs and save.

  - Random Ex: Name of the function, Head, Time-driven, Day timer, midnight to 1am, notify me daily.

Note that this is just one of many solutions to your problem. Many of them can use python.

Here is a quick example just to illustrate it (a separate answer would be needed by someone more experienced with python than me): you could use a github action to run a python script in a github repo at intervals. Use environment variables for your credentials or use a private repo.

And you would need to use a library like [google-api-python-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client)
 to edit the docs

For the actions you could refer to [this](https://github.com/actions/setup-python)

Comment: I guess Python is not **required** for this question, it's just the only coding language I know so I can't really debug/modify any other code. I'll accept this answer if you can help me get this to work, which will probably require me asking very naive questions (e.g., I don't even know what language you this code is in)

Comment: I think I deployed it correctly? I chose "web app" under the type of the deployment (totally guessing, I don't understand how any of this work). It tried running and I get the error "Script function not found: doGet"

Comment: But if I just click "Run" through the script it actually writes to my google doc some documents. Though, I don't understand the dates that the query returns: it seems like all of the returned docs were submitted on Nov 1st / 2nd, which is 1) not the same date. 2) not the most recent date (it would be Friday the 3rd).

Comment: @Penguin The language is Javascript. I will add more details on how i did it in the answer. Don't be obliged to accept this as the answer if it doesn't help you. I was just browsing the questions when i saw the comment about the google app script and became curious since i never used it. And then shared my little experience here.

Comment: Really appreciate it! I was playing with it throughout the day and I think if I understand correctly I don't actually need to deploy anything, but just create a trigger. Though I'm not sure and also not entirely sure why it retrieves documents from Nov 1/2 instead of the latest date

Comment: That must be a limitation of the http://arxiv.org/rss/cs news feed. For example, right now it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Note also that when i use the arxiv advanced search the newest article in computer science is from nov 2: https://arxiv.org/search/advanced?advanced=&terms-0-operator=AND&terms-0-term=&terms-0-field=title&classification-computer_science=y&classification-physics_archives=all&classification-include_cross_list=include&date-year=&date-filter_by=date_range&date-from_date=2023-11-02&date-to_date=2023-11-06&date-date_type=submitted_date&abstracts=show&size=50&order=-announced_date_first

Comment: When I click "Run" it does save documents to the google doc, so not sure what you mean by it's not returning anything. Some of them are now from Nov 3rd actually. Though some are still Nov 2nd (and one from Oct 31st for some reason). Wondering if it can only query a day before (the current latest one is Nov 6th)

Comment: I think that this solution is actually working. Been looking at the documents it returns in the past 2 days and I think arxiv might allow it to query documents up to a day before -- the current ones are mostly from Nov 6th (latest documents on arxiv are from the 7th). I think that the reason for the weird dates is that it query documents that had changes in that date as well. Seems like some of them were uploaded in different dates, but were updated on the 6th. I'm going to give it a few more days just to verify this behavior

Comment: Good to know. There was also the situation that it was the weekend when i tried the code, which might explain (or not) some of the date weirdness, but i suppose that, besides continuous experiment, only talking to arxiv support would one be able to have better info?

Comment: Seems like this stopped working this week for some reason. It was working really well until then. I'm not getting any errors and the script seems to run as normal, getting "Execution completed", but nothing is being appended to the google doc anymore. Not sure what changed

Comment: I tested it and found that the rss structure of the feed changed a little and that is why it wasn't working.  I already edited the script and it seem to be working. They must have been updating the website because the other answer i gave also has problem with its regex of the html. I will also update that answer.

Comment: Thank you again so much!! Looks like it's working with your update!

Answer (score 0):

##### Edit:

- Html has changed so the regex must be adapted :(
- added send error by mail. this feature will ask for extra permission. comment if not needed.

##### Post:

Since the rss solution, i have tinkered a little more with this google app script idea.
It seem that the rss may not be very accurate in terms of the date, so i refactored my previous answer to use the advanced search of arxiv which gives the option to control the dates,

Note that this will directly scrape the html page so you should try to find the attitude of arxiv about it before abusing it without knowing.
Note also that this code use regex which is a very brittle option to analyze html. Just a little change to the html will break it.

```js
function fetchAndScrapePapersPagination() {
  var summary = {
    totalPages: 0,
    totalResults: 0,
    pagesScraped: 0,
    errors: []
  };

  try {
    // Keywords to filter by
    var keywords = [''];
    // Define the parameters
    // Change this to the actual number of articles per page
    var articlesPerPage = 200;
    // Today
    var dateTo = new Date();
    // Get the date 1 days ago
    var dateFrom = new Date();
    dateFrom.setDate(dateTo.getDate() - 3);
    // Format the dates in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format
    var dateFromStr = Utilities.formatDate(dateFrom, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    var dateToStr = Utilities.formatDate(dateTo, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    // Classification
    var classification = "classification-computer_science";

    Logger.log("Fetching response from arxiv.org");
    // Construct the URL
    var url = 'https://arxiv.org/search/advanced?advanced=&terms-0-term=&terms-0-operator=AND&terms-0-field=title&' + classification + '=y&classification-physics_archives=all&classification-include_cross_list=include&date-filter_by=date_range&date-year=&date-from_date=' + dateFromStr + '&date-to_date=' + dateToStr + '&date-date_type=submitted_date&abstracts=show&size=' + articlesPerPage + '&order=-announced_date_first';
    // get the first webpage
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var responseText = response.getContentText();
    // Regular expression to match the total number of results
    var totalResultsRegex = /<h1 class="title is-clearfix">\s*Showing\s*(.*?)\s*<\/h1>/g;
    var totalResultsMatch = totalResultsRegex.exec(responseText);
    if (totalResultsMatch !== null) {
      var matchNumber = totalResultsMatch[1].match(/of ([\d,]+) results/);
      if (matchNumber !== null) {
        var totalResults = parseInt(matchNumber[1].replace(',', ''));
        summary.totalResults = totalResults;
        Logger.log("totalResults got: " + totalResults);

        // Calculate the total number of pages
        var totalPages = Math.ceil(totalResults / articlesPerPage);
        summary.totalPages = totalPages;
        if (totalPages > 0) {
          // Google doc
          Logger.log("Getting Google doc reference");
          // You can find your-google-doc-id in the URL of your Google Doc
          var docId = "your-google-doc-id";
          var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docId);
          var body = doc.getBody();

          Logger.log("scraping pages");
          // Generate and scrape the URLs for each page
          for (var i = 0; i < totalPages; i++) {
            var start = i * articlesPerPage;
            var pageUrl = url + '&start=' + start;
            var pageResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(pageUrl);
            var pageResponseText = pageResponse.getContentText();
            scrapePage(pageResponseText, doc, body, keywords);
            summary.pagesScraped++;
          }
        }
      } else {
        throw new Error('No match found for total results - matchNumber');
      }
    } else {
      throw new Error('No match found for total results - totalResultsMatch');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    summary.errors.push('Error in fetchAndScrapePapersPagination: ' + error.toString());
    Logger.log('Summary of fetchAndScrapePapersPagination: \n' +
      'Total Results: ' + summary.totalResults + '\n' +
      'Total Pages: ' + summary.totalPages + '\n' +
      'Pages Scraped: ' + summary.pagesScraped + '\n' +
      'Errors: ' + summary.errors.join(', '));
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: "your-email@example.com",
      subject: "Error in fetchAndScrapePapersPagination",
      body: 'Error in fetchAndScrapePapersPagination: ' + error.toString(),
    });
  } finally {
    Logger.log('Summary of fetchAndScrapePapersPagination: \n' +
      'Total Results: ' + summary.totalResults + '\n' +
      'Total Pages: ' + summary.totalPages + '\n' +
      'Pages Scraped: ' + summary.pagesScraped + '\n' +
      'Errors: ' + summary.errors.join(', '));
  }

}


function scrapePage(responseText, doc, body, keywords) {
  try {
    // Regular expression to match the list items
    var listItemRegex = /<li class="arxiv-result">(.*?)<\/li>/gs;
    var match;
    while ((match = listItemRegex.exec(responseText)) !== null) {
      var listItemHtml = match[1];

      // Regular expressions to match the title and link
      var titleRegex = /<p class="title is-5 mathjax">(.*?)<\/p>/s;
      var linkRegex = /<a href="(.*?)">/s;

      var titleMatch = titleRegex.exec(listItemHtml);
      var linkMatch = linkRegex.exec(listItemHtml);

      if (titleMatch && linkMatch) {
        var title = titleMatch[1].toLowerCase().trim(); // Trim the title
        var link = linkMatch[1];

        for (var j = 0; j < keywords.length; j++) {
          var temp = keywords[j].toLowerCase();
          var test = title.includes(temp);
          if (test) {
            var listItem = body.appendListItem(title);
            listItem.setLinkUrl(link);
            break;
          }
        }
      } else {
        throw new Error('No match found for title or link');
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: "your-email@example.com",
      subject: "Error in scrapePage",
      body: 'Error in scrapePage: ' + error.toString(),
    });
  }
}
```

The rest will stay the same as my earlier answer.
I hope that this may be useful to someone just as in many other occasions i was helped by such random codes.